# second sorting with php usort

Tags: php, arrays, usort

So Ive got a pretty big array of data and need to sort them by two criteria.

There is variable `$data['important']` and `$data['basic']`.

They are simple numbers and I am using uasort to sort 
`$data` firstly by important and then by basic.

So

```
Important | Basic
10        | 8
9         | 9
9         | 7
7         | 9
```

The usort function is a simple

```
public function sort_by_important($a, $b) {

        if ($a[important] > $b[important]) {
            return -1;
        } 
        elseif ($b[important] > $a[important]) {
            return 1;
        } 
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

How can I re-sort the array to the second variable and keep the Important ordering?

Thanks everyone.

**EDIT**

How about adding a third sorting option after this even? So Important > Basic > Less

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really should use `array_multisort()`,

```
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $important[$key]  = $row['important'];
    $basic[$key] = $row['basic'];
}

array_multisort($important, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC,
                $basic, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC,
                $data);
```

but if you must use `usort()`:

```
public function sort_by_important($a, $b) {

    if ($a[important] > $b[important]) {
        return -1;
    } elseif ($b[important] > $a[important]) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        if ($a[basic] > $b[basic]) {
            return -1;
        } elseif ($b[basic] > $a[basic]) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply use array_multisort()

```
public function sort_by_important($a, $b) { 
    if ($a['Important'] > $b['Important']) { 
        return -1; 
    } elseif ($b['Important'] > $a['Important']) { 
        return 1; 
    } else { 
        if ($a['Basic'] > $b['Basic']) { 
            return -1; 
        } elseif ($b['Basic'] > $a['Basic']) { 
            return 1; 
        } else { 
            return 0; 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: array_multisort was the right answer, Ive got to give the points to kenny because he gave me the answer on the place, placing the order into seperate variables was the bit that confused me. Thanks for your help!