# Merge arrays at correct position while maintaining order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, array-merge

I have two arrays, both have a `position`. I need to merge them together, in their correct positions, while maintaining the order of the elements in each array.

```
$array1 = array(
    array('name' => 'Bob', 'position' => 1),
    array('name' => 'Tim', 'position' => 1),
    array('name' => 'Alf', 'position' => 3),
    array('name' => 'Jon', 'position' => 3) 
);

$array2 = array(
    array('name' => 'Tom', 'position' => 2),
    array('name' => 'Joe', 'position' => 2),
    array('name' => 'Jim', 'position' => 2),
    array('name' => 'Kev', 'position' => 2)
);
```

The output I would like is:

```
$output = array(
    array('name' => 'Bob', 'position' => 1),
    array('name' => 'Tim', 'position' => 1),
    array('name' => 'Tom', 'position' => 2),
    array('name' => 'Joe', 'position' => 2),
    array('name' => 'Jim', 'position' => 2),
    array('name' => 'Kev', 'position' => 2),
    array('name' => 'Alf', 'position' => 3),
    array('name' => 'Jon', 'position' => 3) 
);
```

I thought the best way to do it would be to use `array_merge()`, merging the two arrays, then use a simple `usort()` to sort them based on their position. However, when I do this, the order of elements from `$array2` isn't correct:

```
$output = array_merge($array1, $array2);

usort($output, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['position'] > $b['position'];
});

var_dump($output);
```

Which outputs:

```
$output = array(
    array('name' => 'Bob', 'position' => 1),
    array('name' => 'Tim', 'position' => 1),
    array('name' => 'Tom', 'position' => 2),
    array('name' => 'Joe', 'position' => 2),
    array('name' => 'Kev', 'position' => 2), // Should be 'name' => 'Jim'
    array('name' => 'Jim', 'position' => 2), // Should be 'name' => 'Kev'
    array('name' => 'Alf', 'position' => 3),
    array('name' => 'Jon', 'position' => 3) 
);
```

Is there a way to solve this problem, or a better way of doing it altogether?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875601/second-sorting-with-php-usort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solves my problem, but it needs the `positions` in `$array1` to be sorted ascending (as they are in the code above).

```
$position = $array2[0]['position'];
foreach ($array1 as $key => $arr) {
    if ($position < $arr['position']) {
        $insertAtKey = $key;
        break;
    }
}
array_splice($array1, $insertAtKey, 0, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it involves touching the sub-arrays, so you'll have to make sure the "cache" key is not preserved:

Edit: Version 2

```
function position_merge(array $arr1,array $arr2)
{
    $result=array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
    array_walk($result,function(&$item,$idx){
        $item["array_index"]=$idx;// Make sure this key is not used
    });
    usort($result,function($a,$b){
        return $a["position"]-$b["position"]?:$a["array_index"]-$b["array_index"];
    });
    array_walk($result,function(&$item){
        unset($item["array_index"]);
    });
    return $result;
}
```

[Online demo](http://3v4l.org/BgDK0)

`print_r(position_merge($array1,$array2));` will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bob
            [position] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Tim
            [position] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Tom
            [position] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Joe
            [position] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jim
            [position] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Kev
            [position] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => Alf
            [position] => 3
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jon
            [position] => 3
        )

)
```

---

Old version 1:

```
function position_merge(array $arr1,array $arr2)
{
    function addIndex(&$item,$idx)
    {
        $item["array_index"]=$idx;// Make sure this key is not used
    }
    function rmIndex(&$item)
    {
        unset($item["array_index"]);
    }
    array_walk($arr1,"addIndex");
    array_walk($arr2,"addIndex");
    $result=array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
    usort($result,function($a,$b){
        return $a["position"]>$b["position"]?1:($a["position"]<$b["position"]?-1:$a["array_index"]-$b["array_index"]);
    });
    array_walk($result,"rmIndex");
    return $result;
}
```

[Online demo](http://3v4l.org/qTSiL)

Answer (score 0):

**Output:** http://codepad.org/K8pCY1yD

**Code:**

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
    array('name' => 'Bob', 'position' => 1),
    array('name' => 'Tim', 'position' => 1),
    array('name' => 'Alf', 'position' => 3),
    array('name' => 'Jon', 'position' => 3)
);
$array2 = array(
    array('name' => 'Tom', 'position' => 2),
    array('name' => 'Joe', 'position' => 2),
    array('name' => 'Jim', 'position' => 2),
    array('name' => 'Kev', 'position' => 2)
);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);

$sorted = array();
foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
    $sorted[$key] = $row['position'];
}
array_multisort($sorted, $result);
?>
<pre>
<?php print_r($result); ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this sorts the elements using `SORT_ASC`, I need the order of the elements to be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is helpfull for preserving the order

```
 $arr =  array_merge($array1, $array2) ;
    $result=array();
    $len = sizeof($arr);
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
      $result[$arr[$i]['position']][] = $arr[$i];
    }
    ksort($result);
    $arr = array();
    foreach($result as $rs){
       $arr  = array_merge($arr,$rs); 
    }
    unset($result);
    print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

A brute-force solution. It messes array pointers, unless you want to do a copy.

```
function merge (&$a, &$b)
{
    $c = array();
    $ea = reset ($a);
    $eb = reset ($b);
    do
    {
        if (!$ea) 
            { $c[]=$eb; $eb=next($b); }
        else if (!$eb) 
            { $c[]=$ea; $ea=next($a); }
        else if ($ea['position'] < $eb['position'])
            { $c[]=$ea; $ea=next($a); }
        else                                        
            { $c[]=$eb; $eb=next($b); }
    } while ($eb || $ea);
    return $c;
}
```

output

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=> string(3) "Bob"
    ["position"]=> int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=> string(3) "Tim"
    ["position"]=> int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=> string(3) "Tom"
    ["position"]=> int(2)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=> string(3) "Joe"
    ["position"]=> int(2)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=> string(3) "Jim"
    ["position"]=> int(2)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=> string(3) "Kev"
    ["position"]=> int(2)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=> string(3) "Alf"
    ["position"]=> int(3)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=> string(3) "Jon"
    ["position"]=> int(3)
  }
}
```